# Windows anaconda prompt with git branch?

Tags: git, anaconda, branch, prompt

Is there a way of getting the git branch to show up in the anaconda prompt on the prompt line?

I am using windows 11 with anaconda installed on it and git installed.
Git and conda are both fully working.

I can show the branch using `git branch` but to avoid errors, I want to know the branch at every prompt.

I could not find any instructions for adding the git branch prompt to the conda prompt.